# asp.net Identity ResetPassword UserId not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2

My Reset Password function has stopped working and i don't know what im done, because it was working yesterday.

I can click on the link i get in the email an then i get to the asp.net error page

**UserId not found.
System.InvalidOperationException: UserId not found.**

```
            var manager = Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text);

if (user == null || !manager.IsEmailConfirmed(user.Id))
            {
                FailureText.Text = "Användaren existerar inte eller så är inte användarkontot bekräftat, bekräfta konto och försök sedan igen.";
                ErrorMessage.Visible = true;
                ConfirmAccount.Visible = true;
                return;
            }

            string code = manager.GeneratePasswordResetToken(user.Id);
            string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetResetPasswordRedirectUrl(code, Request);
            manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Återställ Lösenord", "Återställ lösenord klicka <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">Här</a>.");
```

EMail

```
        public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your email service here to send an email.

        try
        {

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("email");
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(message.Destination));
            msg.Subject = message.Subject;
            msg.Body = message.Body;

            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;

            return smtpClient.SendMailAsync(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }


    }

}
```

The EmailConfirmation is almost the same and its working:

```
        string code = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);
        string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);
        manager.SendEmail(user.Id, "Bekräfta ditt konto",  "Bekräfta genom att klicka <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">Här</a>.");
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code and seeing where the error occurs?

Comment: How are you getting user ?

Comment: @muddymess ResetPassword.aspx.cs has no Page_Load event i don't know where to set the break point. this was page was in the template when the project was created i haven't touch it. But the generated code must be wrong somehow. the only ting i changed from the created template is the language of the text.

Comment: @ŁukaszTrzewik ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text);
Maybe it shuld be find by email or is doesnt matter because i have email as username, i havent change it and it have worked before

Comment: put the breakpoint on ApplicationUser user = manager.FindByName(Email.Text); and then step through the code

Comment: I find my error, i have by mistake put the page on a masterpage that you have to be logged in to access.